# WKInterfaceImage startAnimating error

Tags: ios, watchkit

I'm clueless why this simple animation code is not working on the Apple Watch.

```
-(void)showLoadingScreen
{
    [self.loadingImage setHidden:NO];
    [self.loadingImage setImageNamed:@"loading1"];
    [self.loadingImage startAnimating];
}
```

More details:

- loadingImage is declared as `IBOutlet WKInterfaceImage
  *loadingImage;`
- loading1, loading2, loading 3.... are a set of png images added to
  the Images.xcassets folder in the WatchKit Extension
- Moving the loading images to the WatchKit App folder doesn't help
- When I don't call "startAnimating", a single loading images is
  correctly displayed. (So, loadingImage isn't staying hidden due to some other code.)
- I also tried replacing the loadingImages with a few other pictures,
  but I get the same result.
- Works neither on the simulator nor on the device.
- It's a watchOS 2 app.

Any ideas on what could be wrong?

Comment: The image name should just be "loading" without the 1

Comment: They also need to be in the watch app's asset catalog, not the extension's

Comment: @dan: Thanks! That works.